# How to increase speaker/call volume? (cm11.2)

Tags: volume-control, cyanogenmod, volume

Sometimes after I install new version of cm speaker volume is too low. Then I install another version and it is ok. I did some search and found this post (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2400231)  describing how to fix that for Samsung.

The exact line I you need to edit is `RX5 Digital Volume:1:65%` but I did not find that one in my 'snd_soc_msm_2x' config file.

Any one could explain how to fix the volume for HTC One XL? **I do not want to install any sw to make this work.**

Currently I am running 11-20150104-nightly and the volume is very much too low. My snd_soc_msm_2x looks like

```
Code:

EnableSequence
    'SLIM_0_RX Channels':0:eek:ne
    'RX3 MIX1 INP1':0:RX1
    'RX4 DSM MUX':0:DSM_INV
    'LINEOUT1 DAC Switch':1:1
    'LINEOUT3 DAC Switch':1:1
    'LINEOUT1 Volume':1:73
    'LINEOUT3 Volume':1:73
    'RX3 Digital Volume':1:73
    'RX4 Digital Volume':1:73
    'SPK AMP EN Switch':1:1
EndSequence
```

The original steps how to fix it from the link above are....

```
Code:

Navigate to device folders.
Open "etc" folder.
Open "snd_soc_msm" folder.
Open file "snd_soc_msm_2x" file with editor.
Look for the following section below, it is at 41% using ES editor.

SectionDevice
Name "Speaker"
Comment "Speaker Rx device"

EnableSequence
'PRI_RX Channels':0:Two
'RX5 MIX1 INP1':0:RX1
'RX5 MIX1 INP2':0:RX2
'RX6 DSM MUX':0SM_INV
'LINEOUT2 Volume':1:100%
'LINEOUT4 Volume':1:100%
'RX5 Digital Volume':1:65%
EndSequence

The exact line you want to edit is
'RX5 Digital Volume':1:65%

Only change the percentage amount, and only change it in small increments
```

Comment: Do you have a custom kernel? Do you have the s-tweaks app? Some kernels let you change these settings easily through a GUI. Alternatively you may have to install CyanogenMod DSP or Viper4Android or such. I know you don't want to but it's a possibility. Also nightlies have tons of bugs so you can't rely on them as a daily driver (as I'm sure you know).

Comment: @RossC: I don't have custom kernel, just ordinary cm. I don't have s-tweaks app. Before I posted this question I did some search and reading the found that " CyanogenMod DSP" usually did not help. Then I found the code above and thought that that's generic solution to my issue....

Comment: Just in case, have you tried using something like viper4android? It has inbuilt function to increase volume gain from system's limits. Instead of editing system files you can try using that too (since its only louder volume output that matters right?) And make sure you install other sound effect controllers like DSP first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking your phone is codenamed "evita" and the file you're looking at is [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_htc_evita/blob/cm-11.0/dsp/snd_soc_msm/snd_soc_msm_2x#L1628-L1644).  Maybe you could try kicking up those ":1:73"s to ":1:78" or another small increment, restart, and see if it's any louder.  If so, raise the number from 78 to 83 or whatever until you find the volume you like.

You can compare with this [change](https://android.googlesource.com/device/lge/mako/+/76707c8eec60f12d893e652eaeded79ee41b49d1%5E1..76707c8eec60f12d893e652eaeded79ee41b49d1/) for mako (Nexus 4) and this [comment](https://github.com/M1cha/android_device_xiaomi_aries/issues/9) as well...  You might also Google for "msm8960 volume" to see recommendatiosn for other devices that use your qualcomm system-on-a-chip.

I don't know for sure if this will work as expected, but you can report back and let me know if it does.

Comment: That's the question what I need to change. All '73's to something else?

Comment: Yes I would start there.  I don't know if it's the `Digital Volume` or `Lineout Volume` that matters, but you can change them both (or in pairs) to see if it makes a difference.  If you are running CyanogenMod nightlies with root shell, try `adb shell`, then `su`, then `mount -o rw,remount /system` (to put /system in read/write mode) and then `nano /system/etc/snd_soc_msm_2x` and edit and save the change directly to the device.  Then `reboot` to see if it works.